# How to create custom table from two different tables

Tags: sql-server, merge, sql-server-2008-r2, inner-join

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have some issues regarding fetching data from two tables.

I have one (first)table showing below:

[image]

In this table, I have stored a set of id for the second table.

This here is the second table:

[image]

Above image is the master table which has primary keys.

Now I want to create custom table that read the data from first table and check that, that id is exist in second table or not if yes than my custom table should have entry regarding it. I also want to get other records from both tables as well in my custom table.

Any solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: "Give me some solution for that." That sounds like a command, if you want answers, better be polite!

Comment: why the id's are in comma separated values has been stored .Really it's against Normalization why it has been stored in such manner

Comment: Yes @mohan111 you are right but as per requirement I must have to do that. So I have to go ahead with this.

Comment: so if the records are there in both tables then it you don't want to enter if the records is not there it should enter into second that's what you want

Comment: @HoneyBadger please give me any solution if you know

Comment: @mohan111 I have to check any one field like second row contains 1,2,3, so I just want to check 1 and 2 and 3 is in table than I want to get records  of respected id in my custom table.

Comment: so you want to check whether id's are there in second table then we need to insert in Custom table. But you are question is not at all clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103277/discussion-between-0mv1-and-mohan111).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we will make them using ID values using PARSE NAME and then compare them with both tables for Existing Records

```
declare @table1 table (ID varchar(10))
insert into @table1(ID) values ('3,4,6'),('1,2,3'),('2,3'),('1,2,3'),('1,2')

declare @table2 table (ID int)
insert into @table2(ID) values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8)

Declare @Custom Table (ID INT)
;WITH CTE AS (

SELECT 
PARSENAME(REPLACE(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),'-','.'),1) 'ID' 
FROM  
(
     SELECT 
     CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([ID], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data 
     FROM @table1     
) AS A 
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))

INSERT INTO @Custom (ID)
Select T.ID from @table2 T
 WHERE   EXISTS 
 (SELECT DISTINCT C.ID 
        FROM CTE C 
    WHERE T.ID = C.ID) 

select * from @Custom
```

Comment: @oMV1 check the solution and modify according to your requirement

Comment: Yes it completely gives me the data what I want thanks mohan111, appreciated

Answer (score 2):

As per my requirement I got this solution on the base of provided answer by mohan111

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
PARSENAME(REPLACE(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),'-','.'),1) 'ID'
FROM  
(
     SELECT 
     CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Id, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
     FROM table1
) AS A 
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))

SELECT ColumnName FROM CTE C 
join table2 im on im.Id = c.ID
```